# ¿Un constructor pasa a ser parte del objeto cuando es llamado para la creación de este?

Tags: java

¿Un constructor pasa a ser parte del objeto cuando es llamado para la creación de este y por eso puede acceder a todos los miembros que están definidos en el ámbito de este objeto?

Se que el constructor sirve para crear la dirección en memoria en donde se guardara  la información del objeto (atributos y métodos)

**¿Se que el constructor es un método publico de la clase y por ello puede ser invocado desde cualquier parte. Pero es parte del objeto en si mismo?**

**¿por cada llamada al constructor se podría decir que ahora esa llamada al constructor es parte del objeto (de su ámbito el cual es la clase) y por ello puede acceder a todo el ámbito de la clase?(atributos y métodos)**

como por ejemplo cuando dentro de el hacemos uso de los miembros del objeto actualmente creados para iniciarlos con valores específicos?

Ejemplo:

```
class Persona{
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private int edad;

public Persona(){
    nombre="Elliot";
    apellido="Williamson";
    edad=12;
    imprimir_datos();
}
```

}

Si no es así, ¿que hace que el constructor pueda acceder a los miembros del objeto actualmente creado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método constructor, que en este caso se llama `Persona` inicializa los valores para las propiedades de la clase `Persona`, que son:

- nombre
- apellido
- edad

Cuando creas un objeto haciendo instancia de la clase, por ejemplo:

```
Persona persona = new Persona();
```

El primer método que se ejecuta de manera automática es: `Persona` que al tener valores declarados para cada una de las propiedades; entonces las inicializa en la instanciación con dichos valores.

El método constructor puede acceder a dichas propiedades, por que se encuentra dentro del mismo ámbito que ellas; es decir dentro del alcance de la clase `Persona`.

Además de lo anterior, el constructor también podría tener la siguiente estructura:

```
public Persona(String nombre, String apellido, int edad){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.edad = edad;
}
```

Lo anterior indica que el método constructor `Persona` estará listo para recibir 3 valores e inicializarlos con el cuerpo de la clase, pero no le estamos indicando de manera explícita dichos valores; hasta que se hace lo siguiente:

```
Persona persona = new Persona("stack", "over", 10);
```

Lo anterior, indica que la clase al momento de instanciarla a un objeto espera la declaración de 3 argumentos que dentro de ella serán procesados por el constructor y pasarán a formar parte de los valores de cada propiedad declarada.

Comment: ¿Lo que hace por ejemplo java detrás de cámaras entonces es crear todo el objeto y llamar al método constructor de ese objeto en el punto en donde hago la instrucción de instanciacion y ese constructor vendría siendo el que me devuelve la referencia de todo el objeto? Es correcta esta interpretación?

Comment: Cuando creas la instancia de la clase Persona, el constructor se ejecuta para esa instanciación; desde ese punto puedes acceder a los valores provistos para las propiedades o como en mi segundo ejemplo puedes pasárselos como argumentos. En cualquiera de los 2 casos el constructor entra en acción cuando se crea dicha instancia de la class `Persona` @JuanSandoval

Comment: Creo que ya entendí, ¿entonces el constructor es parte del objeto que ya se creo y este método nos ayuda a obtener la referencia del objeto al cual pertenece?

¿Mientras el constructor no nos devuelva esa referencia, lo único a lo que tenemos acceso del objeto creado es el constructor en si por ser parte del objeto que se creo?

Eso fue lo que entendi de esta parte de tu respuesta:

"El primer método que se ejecuta de manera automática es: Persona que al tener valores declarados para cada una de las propiedades; entonces las inicializa en la instanciación con dichos valores"

Gracias!

Comment: **Parte 1**: *El objeto persona es una abstracción de la clase Persona*, de un modo mas simple, la instancia genera la construcción de una clase cuando este es declarado, es decir la existencia del objeto **persona** de la clase Persona genera la ejecución del método constructor **Persona**. cuando dicho objeto este creado tu vas a tener acceso por fuera de la clase a todos los métodos y propiedades cuyo modificador de acceso  no lo restrinja; es decir  en tu ejemplo no vas a poder acceder a la propiedad **name** de este modo: `System.out.println(persona.name);`

Comment: **Parte 2**:  por que es de tipo **private**, lo único que vas a lograr es o imprimir en pantalla su valor o como en mi segundo ejemplo pasarle un parámetro a la clase para dicha propiedad, pero no establecerlo de este modo: `System.out.println(persona.name = "peter");`

Answer (score -1):

Para que lo veas mas facil... el constructor es el método que SIEMPRE se ejecuta en cuanto creas una nueva instancia de la clase.

Y al ser un método mas, puede acceder sin ningun problema a los atributos de la clase, o incluso a otros métodos.

Por ejemplo:
Persona vPersona = new Persona();

Justo en ese momento se acaba de ejecutar el método Persona().

Entonces por que el constructor puede ver las variables? es por que es el método que se ejecuta enseguida de que creamos una nueva instancia.

Saludos xD!